# Too many re-renders - while trying to put props(if exists) in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am transfer an props from father component to child component.

On the child component I want to check if the father component is deliver the props,
If he does, i"m putting it on the state, If not I ignore it.

```
if(Object.keys(instituteObject).length > 0)
    {
        setInnerInstitute(instituteObject)
    }
```

For some reason the `setInnerInstitute()` take me to infinite loop.
I don't know why is that happening and how to fix it.

`getInstitutesById()` - Is the api call to fetch the objects.

Father component(EditInstitute):

```
const EditInstitute = props => {
    const {id} = props.match.params;
    const [institute, setInstitute] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => { //act like componentDidMount
        getInstitutesById({id}).then((response) => {
            setInstitute(response)
        })
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <InstituteForm instituteObject={institute.object}/>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Child component(InstituteForm):

```
const InstituteForm = (props) => {
    const {instituteObject = {}} = props // if not exist default value = {}
    const [innerInstitute, setInnerInstitute] = useState({})
    if (Object.keys(instituteObject).length > 0) // if exists update the state.
    {
        setInnerInstitute(instituteObject)
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            not yet.
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your state an array or an object? You are passing the .object property to the child, which isn't going to exist on an array.

Comment: @JaredSmith, Thanks for notice, the prop that I've delivered is an object, I've change it into `{}` and the result remain same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you are changing your `InstituteForm`'s state causing this error. You can try using the `useEffect` hook to change your `innerInstitute` based on `instituteObject`. That's why you need to also add `instituteObject` in the dependency array of that `useEffect` hook.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const InstituteForm = (props) => {
    const {instituteObject = {}} = props // if not exist default value = {}
    const [innerInstitute, setInnerInstitute] = useState({})
    
    useEffect(() => {
        // this is be evoked only when instituteObject changes
        if (Object.keys(instituteObject).length > 0){
            setInnerInstitute(instituteObject)
        }
    }, [instituteObject])

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            not yet.
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```